# SQL Server : Merge query for insert and update; Will it do delete operations also?

Tags: sql-server, merge, logic

I have the below query. I was under the impression, only update and insert operations would take place based on the conditions. But with this query, DELETE operations also take place which was a bit of a surprise...

Can someone please explain how DELETE operations work? Thanks in advance!

```
MERGE Accts AS TARGET
USING @Merge AS SOURCE ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.Id 
                       AND TARGET.PId = SOURCE.PId

WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE 
         SET TARGET.BId = SOURCE.Id,
             TARGET.Linkid = SOURCE.Linkid

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
     INSERT (Cd, BId, Alias, PId, Linkid, TranId) 
     VALUES (SOURCE.SubId, SOURCE.Bd, SOURCE.Alias, SOURCE.PId, SOURCE.Linkid, @tranId)
    ;
```

Comment: The above won't delete anything, there's no `DELETE` operation in it.

Comment: You can implement deleting data just as you would use `update` or `insert` in your example, which does not actually have a `delete` statement?

Comment: Are you confusing UPDATE with DELETE?   UPDATE changes your values so it may appear that a value was DELETED but in fact has just changed value. As mentioned there is no explicit DELETE in your code